# What does the "0b" mean at the begining of the byte 0b1100010?

Tags: python, binary

As part of a small python project I'm working on, I needed to convert text to a binary string. To accomplish this I used

```
list(map(bin, bytearray(message, 'utf8')))
```

The result was `0b1100010` and I get the `1100010` part, but what does the `0b` part mean?

Comment: maybe binary representation! What do you think ? Did you try to google it ?

Comment: According to Wikipedia: ["a prefix indicating binary format, common in programming languages"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number#Representation). Now that wasn't hard to find on the internet....

Comment: to be fair, they did at least make my search quicker. The Wikipedia redirect from "0b (prefix)" points to the top of the binary number article (I think I will edit that redirect right now to be more direct...), but this question came up first on DuckDuckGo and answered my question more quickly. My question, by the way, was "in what language did I see 0b used to indicate binary?", so I'm not sure Wikipedia's explanation would've helped either way!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is how Python tells you what base the number is:

Base 2 looks like this:

```
0b111010
```

Base 16 looks like this:

```
0x...
```

Base 8 looks like this:

```
0o...
```

(also `0...` in Python 2)

Answer (score 5):

`0b` is the Python prefix for the representation of binary numbers.

For example:

```
>>> bin(1024)  # Convert an integer number to a binary string
'0b10000000000'
```

Answer (score 3):

The "0b" is a prefix to denote that the number is in binary. A similar thing is done in hexadecimal where numbers start with "0x".

Answer (score 1):

It also took me alot of time to figure this out, it's so simple,
so for base 2 numbers like 0b01100010 (which is 98 base 10 written in base 2) the '0b' at the begining of the number is just to signify that it's a binary number.

Same case for 0x62 (is just 98 written in hexadecimal) the '0x' at the beining is just to identify the number as hexadecimal.

This is important this way, 98 != 0x98.